# HandleAction issue when App Killed - Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification

I have an interesting issue. I am implementing Quick reply on my app. Basically, when the user gets a notification, he can answer from the notification (like iMessage or whatsapp)When the app is running or background, it works like a charm. But as soon as the app is being killed, the response will never be sent and the app won't be able to get any further notification. So to sum up, after the app killed, if the user receive one notification and answer to it, he will not be able to receive anymore notification until he lunches the app.

Any idea?

Thank you very much

**EDIT:** I found that when calling Handle Action the fonction RegisteredForRemoteNotifications was called. The problem was that the phone wasn't able to register the phone but It was succeeded when calling UnregisterAllAsync... So my phone wasn't registered anymore. Hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: Are you using silent push notifications, with the "content-available" key? My understanding is that an app killed by the user won't be able to receive that type of push notification until it is launched again by the user.

Comment: Basically, I am using the same type of notification. There is, indeed, the content-available, but the notification displayed because there is also and alert and a body. When the app is killed i am getting the notification but I  respond no more notification reaches the phone. I am going to try by removing "content-available".

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you sending a single notification payload with content-available, alert, and other keys? Apple's documentation says not to do that. Also "I am getting the notification but I respond no more notification reaches the phone" - I don't quite understand. You get the notification but the phone doesn't?

Comment: I am going to be as clear as possible.
Here is the situation: I am sending push notification to my phone after I push the home button. so The app is background . I receive every notification. I can answer back to all messages no problem it works like a charm. But now, I kill the app (swiping up). After that, I send a message, the push notification recheas the phone, and I use the notification to answer back to the message. After, I send a new message but the notification DOES NOT appear! Since the last notification, no way to receive a notification.